# Some doubts about the usage of Past Perfect in these context

Tags: past-tense, present-tense, exam-questions, past-vs-past-perfect

I am encountering some problems filling these space in this exercises:

> A: **Have you seen** Matt recently?
>   B: Matt? He’s in Canada.
>   A: Really? How long **has he been** in Canada?
>   B: About a year now. ______ (I / see) him a few days before **he went**. **He had been** unemployed for months, so **he decided** to try his luck
>   somewhere else. ______ (he / really / look forward) to going.

My answer was:
**I had seen**
Because you are saying that something (seeing *Matt*) is happened before something-else (his departure), for this reason I thought was correct to use the Past Perfect, to arrange the events happened in their properly timeline.
**He had been looking forward**
Based on the exercise's context, it makes me think that *Matt* (1) has been thinking about it for a long period of time, (2) it happened in the past, therefore, once again I thought the Past Perfect would have matched correct here.

Instead, the book says:
**I saw**
**He was really looking forward**

Could I ask you guys why my answers are wrong? Thank you.

Comment: If the speaker had said 'Matt got in touch with me soon after he arrived. I hadn't expected to hear from him so soon because _I had seen him_ a few days before he went', the past perfect would have been used because the two incidents were related. It's hard to explain - it's just one of those things that native speakers do automatically.

Comment: Related (but not really a duplicate) [Canonical Post #2: What is the perfect, and how should I use it?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/13255/9161)

Comment: "I saw " is used because "before"  is used in the sentence, which makes the sequence clear, so past perfect is unnecessary. It doesn't say that he had been looking  forward to it for a long time, it just says he was looking forward to it. This happened in the past, over a year ago .

Comment: @anouk about the 1^ question, okay. So basically every time there is an adverb of time in the phrase, and I'm not sure which one to use between Past Simple and Past Perfect, the Past Perfect it's not necessary, isn't it?

Comment: "before" and "after" make the sequence of events clear, so with these past perfect is optional and you can use the past simple.

Comment: @anouk Okay, thanks